# Temporary Environment Variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, environment-variables

Try to bear with me as I am fairly new to this and don't have much coding experience.

Im trying to use a ruby script to add a location to my PATH variable. So far I just have

```
path = ENV['PATH'].to_s

ENV['PATH'] = path + ";" + location

print ENV['PATH']
```

The problem is that the file seems to be added to the PATH and prints with it, but when I go check my path variable the new location is not there.

Also, when I run a separate script of which is one line:

```
print ENV['PATH']
```

the new location is not there either.

My question is is there a way to make the new PATH "save" instead of reverting to the old PATH when the script is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am not mistaken you cannot really edit the environment variables.

When loading your script ruby loads all the currently known environment variables and adds the values to `ENV`.

When editing it, it will only be changed temporarily for the current execution.

If you want to change it and want it to persist you will have to e.g. use `system`

```
system("export PATH=$PATH:YOUR_PATH")
```

Same as you would do it in the CLI

Comment: Alright, I guess that makes sense, is there a similar function in windows?

Comment: `system()` also changes it temporarily, in fact, it's even worse since it only changes it inside the `system()` shell.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is generate a shell command to be evaluated outside the Ruby script and inside the shell you are running.

Something like this should work:

```ruby
puts "export PATH=#{ENV['PATH']};#{location}"
```

Then, in the shell you do

```sh
eval $(ruby_script)
```

However, since you seem to want to run this in Windows you probably want to use command substitution, in which case you output the location directly:

```ruby
puts location
```

And in the Windows shell:

```sh
set PATH=%PATH%;(ruby_script)
```

Answer (score 0):

colon ":" is the field separator for PATH not semicolon ";" in Unix. Your example worked just fine for me today when I changed the semicolon to a colon.